# Remove specific char in the beginning of the line if it present in vim

Tags: vim

Just another vim source code comment question here. I have this mapping for my python source code files:

```
map <C-C> <Home>i#<Esc>
imap <C-C> <Home>#<Esc> i
```

On Ctrl-C it puts # in the beginning if the line to comment it out. This improves productivity a lot. But when I want to uncomment lines, I have to do this manually, meaning going to the first character of each commented line and remove it. This is very annoying. At the first glance, I can just bind Home-x to some key, but I can occasionally remove an innocent space or something else in case I misshit and do this on line that has no # character at the beginning of it. I first try to do some replacement with :%s// for a single line, but that has an unwanted affect - it triggers a search and highlights 'pattern' in other lines. In case of a single # character it is a fail.
Can anybody suggest how to remove a specified character in the beginning of current line in case it present and do nothing, if not, without using pattern replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a simple function to Toggle comment in the line:

```
function! ToggleComment()
    let l:pos = col('.')
    if getline('.') =~ '\v(\s+|\t+)?#'
        exec 'normal! _"_x'
        let l:pos -= 1
    else
        exec 'normal! I#'
        let l:pos += 1
    endif
    call cursor(line("."), l:pos)
endfunction
nnoremap <Leader>t :call ToggleComment()<CR>
inoremap <Leader>t <C-o>:call ToggleComment()<CR>
```

I recommend Tim Pope's plugin [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) because is way more complete. But of course our idea gives you guys a glimpse how far we can get with vimscript.

Another approach, which does not need to save windowview and toggles comments in other languages can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/voyeg3r/223f148a115c17a02a15660cc7335f4c)

Comment: Adding comment character does not work if line starts with whitespaces, which is very common for Python code. The # added not at the beginning of the line, but after last space at the beginning of the line. To fix that it is better to use `0i#` instead of `I#`.

Comment: I have changed the function accordingly, now we test first non-blank of the line instead of first column of the line. @[e-pirate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3378886/e-pirate)

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to adopt same function to work for both single char comment in Python and double char comment in C by passing comment char(s) as an argument and checking for two chars if needed? @sergioaraujo

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody suggest how to remove a specified character in the beginning of current line in case it present and do nothing, if not, without using pattern replacement?

A solution would be (assuming your cursor is anywhere to the right of `#` when using the map):

```
map <c-c> mmF#x`m
```

A more general solution would be to use a substitution and `histdel()` to delete the last search pattern:

```
function! DelComment()                                                   
  s/^\( *\)#/\1/
  call histdel("search", -1)
  let @/ = histget("search", -1)      
endfunction
```

After executing the function (by selecting it and typing `:@"`) you can map it to `<c-c>`:

```
map <silent> <c-c> mm:silent! call DelComment()<cr>`m
```

I like using marks around functions to retain the cursor position after executing the map. Feel free to remove `mm` and `` `m `` in the above map.